# Neutral leg outlet pluggable detector

Tags: tester

For my certain 240v circuit. I want to know if there is a 2 prong pluggable tester where it can detect if one of the leg of the 240v is grounded or not. Assuming the outlet is only 2 wire. Can one detect whether the 240v is like in Europe where the neutral is one of the two hot legs. Or like in USA where the two hot wire 240v is floating and only the centertap is grounded or the neutral?

Comment: In Europe the neutral is neutral. It is not one of two "hot legs". It is one of the legs on a 230 V circuit. Testing between L and N only checks that there is a potential difference between them. It doesn't test that there is an earth connection and that the neutral is truly neutralised.

Answer (score 1):

There are electrical detectors used for determining if a line is hot. These are one wire detectors. They work by using your body as a capacitive coupling to the environment to generate a pseudo ground. Two of these in parallel, one in each terminal of the outlet would accomplish what you are after, so clearly it is possible. This will still require a human to hold the tester to provide the pseudo ground. without the pseudo ground or any other ground source, it would not be possible.

Comment: Is it just the normal non-contact voltage tester like this?https://www.amazon.com/Non-Contact-Electrical-Detector-Inductive-Multi-meter/dp/B07BDHHSLZ/ref=sr_1_11?s=lamps-light&ie=UTF8&qid=1544068143&sr=1-11&keywords=non+contact+voltage+tester  But I'm not testing if the line is hot.. but if the line is grounded at the utility pole.

Comment: yes. exactly that.

Comment: to test if a line is grounded at the unitility pole you'd need to run a wire to that point (or other known ground) and  measure the resistance.  measuring the voltage is usually easier.

Comment: resistance between what points in the pole?

Comment: resistance to ground.

Comment: If the one leg is grounded at the utility pole, than that leg will not show up as hot using the tester, assuming of course that the utility pole ground is connected to earth ground as it should be.